# Count per Category on Daily basis

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables, Category and Sales. I want to calculate the count of every category on a daily basis.

Category Table

```
id cat_name
01 A
02 B
03 C
```

Sales Table

```
date          cat_id
2015/02/01    01
2015/02/01    01
2015/02/01    03
2015/02/02    02
2015/02/02    03
2015/02/02    03
2015/02/03    01
2015/02/03    02
2015/02/03    02
```

Result

```
date          A     B     C
2015/02/01    2     0     1
2015/02/02    0     1     2
2015/02/03    1     2     0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT s.`date`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN s.cat_id=01 THEN cat_id END) AS A,
COUNT(CASE WHEN s.cat_id=02 THEN cat_id END) AS B,
COUNT(CASE WHEN s.cat_id=03 THEN cat_id END) AS C
FROM sales s
JOIN category c
ON s.cat_id=c.id
GROUP BY s.`date`;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0875a/9)